# Connect Macbook and Android App without internet

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking

I have a computer(Macbook) that is running an Apache xmlrpc server and an Android app running an xmlrpc client. The short story is that I need the app to be able to make rpc calls to the computer, but without using the internet. The android device will be in close proximity to the computer, so if I get the computer's IP I can communicate with it through wifi.

My question is, how do I open this connection up from my Mac and get its IP address? I am very new to anything with networking so I apologize if this is a basic question, but I was not able to find any tutorials online because the search keywords (without internet) gave results with internet in them. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If by "without Internet" you mean over the local network they're both attached to, yes you can.

To get the IP address of the MacBook, open up Terminal.app and type `ifconfig en0`. Assuming you have a new MacBook with no Ethernet port you should get the inet (IP) address listed. If not, it's probably `ifconfig en1`.

You'll also want to make sure your firewall is open on port 80 for the web traffic. System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Firewall > Turn off Firewall. Don't forget to turn it back on when you're done testing. There isn't the option to easily whitelist individual ports unfortunately.